# Как сэмулировать NEW_USER_CONFIRM для конкретного юзера?

Tags: php, битрикс, авторизация, auth

Как правильно вызвать битриксовое почтовое событие, чтобы ушло письмо юзеру с проверочной строкой? Сейчас при релоаде ничего не происходит, сервак ф-ю мейл отрабатывает

Тестирую на индексе для существующего юзера:

```
$eventName = 'NEW_USER_CONFIRM';
    $arFields = Array(
            "USER_ID" => 264,
            "LOGIN" => 'sinecuraweb@gmail.com',
            "NAME" => 'Нео',
            "EMAIL" => 'sinecuraweb@gmail.com'
        );
    $event = new CEvent;
    $event->Send($eventName, SITE_ID, $arFields, "N", 8); //id почтов события ? 
   //$event->Send($eventName, SITE_ID, $arFields, "N", 'main'); // id шабл?
```

Comment: Странный у Вас набор параметров. Почитайте [документацию](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/send.php).

Comment: это **D7** , в доках есть такой пример 
`use Bitrix\Main\Mail\Event;
Event::send(array(
    "EVENT_NAME" => "NEW_USER",
    "LID" => "s1",
    "C_FIELDS" => array(
        "EMAIL" => "info@intervolga.ru",
        "USER_ID" => 42
    ),
)); `   [вот](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/mail/event/send.php)

Comment: все верно. и если обратите внимание что передается в последних двух параметрах и что они должны быть в массиве. у вас совсем не так.